# Print words occurrences from Max to Min in Java (No Streams)

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

Can you please give me advice on how to print word occurrences from the most frequent value to the least frequent?

I've tried different methods, so I stopped on the Map, it gives me a much closer result.

```
public class InputOutput {

    private String wordsFrequency() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt"));
            String words;

            while ((words = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(words);
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    String word = scan.next();
                    if (map.containsKey(word))
                        map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
                    else
                        map.put(word, 1);
                }
                scan.close();
            }
            reader.close();
            Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = map.entrySet();

            for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
                result.append(entry.getKey()).append("\t").append(entry.getValue()).append("\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputOutput requestedData = new InputOutput();

        System.out.println(requestedData.wordsFrequency());

    }
}
```

*File contents:*

```
the day is sunny the the
the sunny is is is is is is
```

*Expected output:*

```
is  7
the 4
sunny   2
day 1
```

*The output I'm getting:*

```
the 4
is  7
sunny   2
day 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do it, but without using streams here's what I came up with:

```
String src = "the day is sunny the the the sunny is is is is is is";

try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new StringReader(src))) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String word = scanner.next();
        map.merge(word, 1, (a, b) -> a + 1);
    }
    Map<Integer, Collection<String>> cntMap = new TreeMap<>(Comparators.reverseOrder());
        
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       Collection<String> list = cntMap.get(entry.getValue());
       if (list == null) {
           list = new TreeSet<>();
           cntMap.put(entry.getValue(), list);
       }
       list.add(entry.getKey());
    }

    for (Entry<Integer, Collection<String>> entry : cntMap.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " : " + entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> frequencies = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
frequencies.sort(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue()).reversed());
```

A List may be sorted, or a TreeSet can be sorted (SortedSet) using a Comparator. Here with a function returning a Comparable value.

Answer (score 1):

The issues with the code you've provided:

- In case of the exception, the stream would not be closed. More over ever if all the data would be successfully read from a file, but exception occur during closing the reader you'll the data because lines of code that are responsible for processing the map will not be executed. Use [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to ensure that your resources would be properly closed.
- Don't cram too much logic into one method. There are at least two responsibilities, and they should reside in separate methods, as the [*Single responsibility principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) suggests.
- Instead of utilizing `Scanner` you can split the line that has been read from a file.
- And your current logic lucks sorting. That's why your current and expected output don't match.

You can generate a map `Map<String, Integer>` representing the frequency of each word.

Then create a *list of entries* of this *map*, sort it based on values in *descending* order.

And finally turn the *sorted list of entries* into a *list* of strings which you can print.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> wordsFrequency(String file) {
    
    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
    
    try (var reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(file))) {
        String[] words = reader.readLine().split(" ");
        for (String word : words) {
        //  frequencies.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum); // an equivalent of the 2 lines below
            int count = frequencies.getOrDefault(word, 0);
            frequencies.put(word, count + 1);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return frequencies;
}

public static List<String> mapToSortedList(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    // sorting the list of entries
    entries.sort(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed());
    
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry :entries) {
        result.add(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mapToSortedList(wordsFrequency("filePath.txt")).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Much appreciate! 
entries.sort(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed());

Comment: @OrestDymarchuk This [method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue()) as well `comparingByKey()` was introduced with Java 8, they can be very handy when need to process the data stored in a map.

Answer (score 1):

You already have your data, here is how to get them in reverse sorted order.

- declare a `SortedSet` using the comparator to compare the the values of the entries
- then add the entries to the `SortedSet` and the will be sorted as they are entered.
- `Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reversed())` is used to sort on the count only and in reversed order.

```
SortedSet<Entry<String,Integer>> set
            = new TreeSet(Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()));
set.addAll(map.entrySet());
```

Then print them.

```
set.forEach(e-> System.out.printf("%-7s : %d%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

For your data, this would print

```
is      : 7
the     : 4
sunny   : 2
day     : 1
```